# How to prove that the dependent variable could not be expressed explicitly in terms of the independent variable(s)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Consider the equation that $$xy=\log{y}+1\text{.}$$
How does one prove that $y$ cannot be expressed explicitly in terms of $x$?

By the way, I do not know how the adverb "explicitly" is strictly defined, though likely it is generally understood. For example, I would call $y=\displaystyle\frac{x-1}{\sin^3{x+1}}$ an explicit expression.

Comment: The second part of your question points to the actual problem. By the implicit function theorem you can figure out whether you can solve locally uniquely for $y$. If that's true, then you have a relation $y=f(x)$ and can simply define this $f$ as the closed solution. For example, what is so explicit about, say, $\sinh$ or $\log$? You need (well, use) a power series, differential equations or integrals to define the latter. Of course you can make the question more precise by asking for, say, rational functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function are related to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the comment by Thomas: you can express $y$ explicitly by $x$ via the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). You have $$\begin{array}{lrl} & xy & = \log(y) + 1 \\ \Rightarrow\ & e^{xy}& =y\cdot e \\ \Rightarrow\ & -xe^{-1} &= -xye^{-xy} \\ \Rightarrow\ & W(-xe^{-1}) &= -xy \\ \Rightarrow\ & y & = -\tfrac 1x W(-xe^{-1}) \end{array}$$